# Fill combobox with datafrom Database and from that combobox fill another combobox with another data from the same database

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

Two ComboBoxes - cmbSupplier and cmbProduct

I want to fill cmbSupplier with supplier names from a table

when I select a value from cmbSupplier
depending on the name selected
Products with the supplier name should fill cmbProduct

private void frmAddOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT sup_name from tbl_supplier",con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            cmbSupplier.Items.Add(dr["sup_name"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();




    }
```

this is the code I use to fill cmbSupplier

I tried using this code to fill cmbProducts but all I get is an error

```
         private void cmbSupplier_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Product_Name from tbl_SupplierItems WHERE supplier_name'" + cmbSupplier.Text + "%'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while(dr.Read())
        {
            cmbProduct.Items.Add(dr["Product_Name"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();



    }
```

Comment: Please, provide *relevant code*

Comment: You would do that with the IndexChanged event on the first combo box. If you want more detailed help you need to provide a LOT more details in your question.

Comment: i update the content of my question I'm sorry if its quite messy

Comment: Before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ You also should learn about the USING clause. Use it around all your IDisposable objects like connections and commands.

Comment: What you have seems to be reasonably close. But you probably want to add cmdProduct.Items.Clear() before you add the new ones. You said you are "getting an error". If you share the error message it would help others to know what the problem is.

Comment: @SeanLange the error is that when I pick a value from cmbSupplier the error shows that the con.Open() was not closed on the cmbSupplier_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: The actual error message would be better than a paraphrasing of it. My guess is it because you don't properly handle your connections. Notice in your code you are opening the connection but the connection is not defined in your method. That means the connection already exists and is open. If you try to open an open connection is doesn't like that. Learn how to properly dispose of your connection with the USING clause like a said before.

Answer (score -1):

The query is not correct.
Instead of

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Product_Name from tbl_SupplierItems WHERE supplier_name'" + cmbSupplier.Text + "%'", con);`

You should write

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Product_Name from tbl_SupplierItems WHERE supplier_name = '" + cmbSupplier.Text + "%'", con);`

Comment: Please don't provide answers that continue the abysmal practice of allowing sql injection.